# "Show code snippet" underline looks buggy

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets

The link shows broken underline in some zoom levels.

Post taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63403377/908879) and I am using `Firefox 79.0`.

[image: image at various zoom levels]

Comment: Stack Exchange only supports a 100 % zoom level, so this bug may be deemed invalid. However, this is indeed reproducible (Firefox Nightly 81.0a1) _only_ for “Show code snippet” links, not for other Markdown links or the “Expand snippet” or “edit the above snippet” links. It’s _not_ reproducible for 100 % zoom, as your screenshot suggests.

Comment: Yes, I reproduce on Firefox 79 on Windows 10. As has been mentioned, zooming is not supported by Stack Exchange, but this bug is reproducible at 100% zoom levels.

Comment: Can also repro on a high-res display (looks fine on a 96ppi one), regression range: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/pushloghtml?fromchange=b338d55d5007ce5a7d4cdce3aaa8e9f63c5555f7&tochange=4cd56624e723867b1e508d73bd8ee82c899f5670 though I don't see a clear culprit there...

Comment: Bug is still present in Firefox 105.0.1. Zoom level 100%, so it's not a zoom issue. The bug is caused by `.show-hide { vertical-align: middle; }`. I assume the style rule is an effort to line up the link text and the chevron icon.